# What is the structure of ATIS (Airline Travel Information System) dataset

Tags: python, dataset, text-mining, recurrent-neural-network

When I use ATIS (Airline Travel Information System) dataset(http://lisaweb.iro.umontreal.ca/transfert/lisa/users/mesnilgr/atis/) to do research in recurrent-neural-network. I am confused with it's structure.

For example, after using `data = pickle.load(open("./dataset/atis.fold0.pkl",  "rb"),encoding='iso-8859-1')` to load the atis.fold0.pkl, I use `print (np.shape(data_train))` to get `(4,)`. I think the data[0] is the training set, the data[1] is the valid set, the data[2] is the test set and the data[3] is the dict.

But when I use `print(np.shape(data[0]))`, I get `(3, 3983)`. I wonder why I get 3 rows in it? what's the difference between these three rows.

And what's the difference between file atis.fold0.pkl, atis.fold1.pkl, atis.fold2.pkl, atis.fold3.pkl, atis.fold4.pkl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
try:
    train_set, valid_set, test_set, dicts = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
except:
    train_set, valid_set, test_set, dicts = pickle.load(f)


print np.shape(train_set)
```

Each of the pickle can be divided into training, validation, testing, and its dictionary. When you see the dictionary elements, they contain the
 words2idx 
tables2idx
labels2idx

Now test the following code

`for i in train_set:
	print len(i[0])`

It will return same length file.
So the First element is the words.Second is the tables2idx and third is final result of slot filling (labels2idx)

Use the dict to decry pt the ids, you will get the meaning.

Comment: are the intents included in this dataset?

Comment: I don't know. But I never came across the intents in this dataset. Can you check it ?

Comment: No, no intents - but there are some at github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/Examples/ATIS/Data